# What's revised mean in editing?

Tags: discussion, support, edits, suggested-edits, editing-help

I did many good edits in past several hours. And most of them got approved through the peer review. For some of the edits, I earned reputation and some I didn't. When I'm looking what I edited. I saw this 'Revision's. I don't know what is mean by 'revised'.

If 'revised' mean removing what I did? But still have my name on the post. See here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31202708/aes-encryption-from-java-to-c-sharp

This edit 'revised' as you can see on the picture. But it still have my edit. And also I didn't get any reputation from it.

[image]

Here is the Suggestions list - [image]

Can some one explain me this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Those are the (approved) edits that you've actually made.  Only the suggestions that were approved go through as actual edits.  Any changes to existing content (posts and tag wikis) are represented as "revised".

There's a also separate [suggestion tab](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4533771/dhanuka-lakshan?tab=activity&sort=suggestions) where you can see the suggested edits and the reviews associated with them.

As for why you didn't get the reputation from the edit, it's possible you've gained the [maximum reputation of 1000](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) from suggested edits.  To check this, visit https://stackoverflow.com/reputation to get an audit of your own reputation.  At the bottom, there will be a summary, which includes how much reputation you've earned from suggested edits.